# Background-image doesn't show on Ionic App

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building an ionic app, and i want to add an image as background for the ionic side menu and i have it like this

**View**

```
 <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
           The content...
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/noticias"><i class="icon ion-ios-paper"></i> Noticias</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/ganados"><i class="icon ion-social-usd"></i> Ganados</ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/indicadores"><i class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right"></i> Indicadores económicos</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Style

```
.menu {
  background-color: #282828;
  background-image: url("../img/bg-side-menu.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; 
}
```

When i watch the app in the desktop browser (Google Chrome and Firefox) the image shows perfectly, but when i use ionic view to watch the app in my android phone the image doesn't show.

Any idea of what could cause this? Thanks a lot for the help!.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is the image source might be a different location on the device? 
On your device see if you can file browse to your app and verify that the image location corresponds to what you have as the image url.